# What disaster considerations should I make for my pet rabbit?

Tags: rabbits, disaster

After reading through http://www.ready.gov/ I have a family plan and am creating a [Disaster Supply Kit](http://www.ready.gov/basic-disaster-supplies-kit).  What considerations should I have for my [house rabbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_rabbit)?  What supplies should I include in the kit for my bunny?

Comment: Kind of related (on "disaster", not "rabbits"): http://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1632/31

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most important things is that you get an appropriately sized travel carrier.  The carrier should be large enough that your rabbit can fit in it comfortably but should not allow room for the rabbit to move a lot when the carrier gets jostled.  During an emergency you likely will not have time to slowly and carefully move your bunny.  A properly sized carrier will help keep your bunny from experiencing trauma from being thrown around its cage.  A bunnies back and neck are relatively fragile so this is important.

[image]  *This is a double carrier for 2 rabbits but you can also find single or triple carriers depending on your need.  These carriers are also available in various sizes.  It is important that your carrier not be too big or too small for your rabbit*

You should have at least a weeks supply of food. Rabbits do not handle stress well and the emergency is going to be enough stress.  Changing its food at this time could very well push it over the edge.  **Stress can kill a rabbit.**  Having a week of the food that it is used to should help your rabbit get through this period, as well as giving you time to find more food.  If you are unable to find a source of the same food your rabbit is used to by day 3 then I would start mixing in what ever food you plan to replace it with.

Your rabbit should be able to handle a few days in the carrier but you will want to find it at least a temporary cage as soon as you get to someplace you can stay for a few days. If that will not be possible then you should have a temporary rabbit sitter that can provide that stable place for your rabbit.  I am against boarding a rabbit at a Vet clinic only because your rabbit is liable to be exposed to some diseases it has no immunity for during a time where it is already stressed.  But if that is your only option your rabbit is better off there than riding in your car.  Having an emergency sitter prepared ahead of time will save you and your bunny stress.

Comment: wire-bottom cages without a place for the rabbit to sit off grid are a no-no.  Rabbits don't have pads on their feet like cats and dogs, and thus the wire cages can really hurt especially if they are forced to stand on them for prolonged periods.  Consider changing your example cage to an appropriately sized cat carrier; there are several made out of cloth that fold down and store nicely.