# What is the shelf life of metoclopromide (Reglan)?

Tags: health, rabbits, medicines

I have metoclopromide (Reglan) oral solution in my [rabbit first aid kit](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/what-should-be-in-a-rabbit-first-aid-kit).  It should be dispensed in a [light-resistant](http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/archives/fdaDrugInfo.cfm?archiveid=3705), [Tightly sealed](http://www.petmd.com/pet-medication/metoclopramide) container and stored at [room temperature](http://www.drugs.com/pro/metoclopramide-oral-solution.html). It has [been suggested](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/my-rabbit-is-hyperventilating-and-cant-get-comfortable-what-is-wrong-with-her/2124#comment4652_2124) that the shelf life of the product is fairly short.  But I am unable to find any reliable references discussing how often it should be replaced.

Is there any published information on how long the drug will remain viable?

Comment: How much do you administer to a rabbit at a time? It comes in pill form, it may be better to keep the pills in your kit since they should have a longer shelf life. If that's not possible (b/c of the dosage used), is it a professionally made solution? In that case I would contact the compounding pharamacy or manufacturer.

Comment: @Zaralynda It is dispensed (from the vet) in liquid form, also from the links in the question, you can see that this is a standard option.  I can not even imagine trying to feed a pill to a rabbit, it would need to be liquid for delivery.

Comment: Even as a standard option, someone has to make it, and that is likely the best place to find an answer for shelf life.

Comment: I just found the shelf life for the pill http://www.medicines.org.uk/emc/medicine/24123/SPC#SHELF_LIFE (3-4 years) finding the same for the liquid is just a matter of looking better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My veterinary pharmacist tells me it has a 1 month shelf life and cannot be frozen.

This seems to conflict with some literature that James dug up that suggests 6 months.

However, I did  stumble upon [this technical document](http://globalrph.com/metoclopramide_dilution.htm) about parenteral preparations of metoclopromide.  It claimed that it's okay to freeze saline mixtures for 4 weeks, but that dextrose formulations will degrade metocloprmide.  Contrairly, it clamined that unfrozen, any mixture should be good for 24 hrs unprotected from light or 48 hrs if protected from light.

Nevertheles, this [research paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2710.1997.tb00016.x/abstract) casts some doubt on about those clams.  Hor et. al found no apparent differenced between metaclopramide's stability at room temperature over a 48 hr time frame in either saline or dextrose solutions, or dark vs light conditions.

In-contrast, during my attempt at [purchaseing the solution](http://www.vetdepot.com/metoclopramide-oral-solution-5-mg-5-ml-pint-473-ml.html) my self, the pharmacy assured me that their solution was good for greater than 6 months.

The discrepancies can best be attributed to formulation, and the addition of stabilizers to some products.

Answer (score 2):

According the flyer for [Emeprid Oral Solution 1 mg/ml metoclopramide(pdf)](https://www.abbeyvet-export.co.uk/pdfs/EMEPRID%20-%20Anti-emetic%20and%20pro-kinetic%20Metoclopramide%20injectable%20and%20oral%20solution.pdf).  The oral solution has an unopened shelf life of 3 years, it is stable after opening for 6 months.  As mentioned in the question, it should be dispensed in a light-resistant, tightly sealed container and stored at room temperature.  There are some references suggesting it is ok to freeze for a short time, but all of these are for injectable when **NOT** mixed with sugar. The syrup is going to have sugar (or should have) so you are probably best to not freeze it.