# Why is my young female rabbit breathing fast.

Tags: rabbits

I have a young female rabbit that I found 4 months ago.  Since then she has had a litter of 7 bunnies.  They are now 13 weeks old.  When I found her she was malnourished and had a respiratory infection.  She was treated for this.  Her lab work and chest xray are now normal however her respiratory rate is still 140. She acts and looks healthy.  Other than her respiratory rate being elevated.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your question implies you have already been to see a vet, and that her respiratory rate has been 140 for 4 months.  What did the vet tell you?  Also if you still have the babies living with mom or living together you are very close to having a lot more bunnies.  Some rabbits can breed as young as 12 weeks. If four of the babies are girls, you could have 35 babies in 3 more weeks, There is more good information in [these posts about rabbit breeding](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits+breeding)

Comment: Related [My rabbit is hyperventilating and can't get comfortable. What is wrong with her?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2123)

Comment: We found homes for all the babies but one.  The one that we kept has been neutered.  Yes,  she has been to the vet and was treated for a respiratory infection and malnourishment.  Chest xray and labs are now normal.  However she is still breathing fast.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably stress.

In the wild, rabbits live in burrows, if you just have her in a hutch, she will be stressed because it seems too exposed to her and she feels trapped with nowhere to run and hide.

Try creating an artificial burrow that is sizable and allows her to hide away.